# JQuery Match Height Not Working on Rails 5.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting the following error after trying to install Jquery Match Height on my Rails app.

[image]

I've tried using the Match Height Gem, simply copy-pasting the entire script into my `application.js`, and (currently) a CDN include on my `application.html.erb`:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.2/jquery.matchHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The same errors are generated regardless.  I have these jquery-related gems installed:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Here's how I'm trying to use Match Height:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.card-img-top').matchHeight();
    $('.card-title').matchHeight();
    $('.card-text').matchHeight();
    $('.card-footer').matchHeight();
  });
</script>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure your matchHeight.js gets loaded before you call the function `macthHeight()`. Could you also check if you can execute the same function after page loads completely and see if you are still getting the error?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Shouldn't the `$(document).ready(function()` take care of that?

Comment: Not always AFAIK..

Comment: Can you just try  my 2nd suggestion?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I get the same error if I do `$('.card-img-top').matchHeight();` in the console after the page has completely loaded.

Comment: Can you confirm if the script has been loaded in the page?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Actually, even though it's there in the source code, it doesn't show up in the sources tab of the inspector console...

Comment: Do you get any console errors for that specific script? Make sure you are not under any proxy and it is blocking the script..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao The only console errors are the ones in the screenshot above. And I have no idea what a proxy is...

Comment: If you look at the screenshot, you see 2 more errors at the end.. Bad HTTP response for the script and failed to load resource is been given.. I suspect some problem with loading script.. Can you try pasting the script url in the browser and see if you are getting js rendered in the browser?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, the url (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.2/jquery.matchHeight.js) is correct.

Comment: I am sure that is correct, but can you try opening that in a different tab and see what you are getting?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, if I open it in a new tab the JS shows up properly.

Comment: Why don't you use rubygems? `https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-matchheight-rails`

Comment: please, update your post with html code having the class '.card-img-top'

Comment: Your error logs just looks strange. Did you include the line in the html Head instead of Body? <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.2/jquery.matchHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

if you use the gem [jquery-matchheight-rails](https://github.com/dassump/jquery-matchheight-rails), no need a CDN include

Add, the following to your JavaScript manifest file:(application.js)

```
//= require jquery.matchHeight
```